# Error sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, ppa

I’m running Ubuntu 14.04. When I run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

I get the following error:

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

I tried to run

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

but it shows:

```
software-properties-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: This is an old post, and maybe the OP no longer cares! However did you try `sudo apt install software-properties-common --reinstall`?

Answer (score 425):

For Ubuntu 14.04 or later you need to install the `software-properties-common` package:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

I found the solution in this blog:
[Ubuntu Server 14.4 (Trusty Tahr) – add-apt-repository: command not found](https://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/ubuntu-server-14-4-trusty-add-apt-repository-command-not-found/)

Comment: That worked for me as well on Debian but only after running "apt-get update" could I install any new ppas.

Answer (score 47):

If you are using an older release of Ubuntu, i.e. before 12.10, it is necessary to install the package `python-software-properties`.

```
sudo apt install python-software-properties
```

Comment: I had this issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This fixed it, but I had to also reboot the server after installing.

Comment: This solved it for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. `software-properties-common` was already installed.

Comment: This solved it for me on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, as `software-properties-common` was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

**Run** `sudo apt-get update`

**Then** `sudo apt install software-properties-common -y`

**Now**, you can use `sudo add-apt-repository`