# unmet dependencies with fresh python3.8 installation on Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python, dependencies

I am trying to install [cerbot](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 server.
I was having some trouble with python, so I removed all python versions from the system. I then downloaded the latest 3.8 release from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/), and  ran

```
make
make install
```

However, when I try to run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
```

I am getting an error telling me that the command cannot be found

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

So I then saw an [answer to this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593433/error-sudo-add-apt-repository-command-not-found) - which is to install the `software-properties-common` package.

However doing so gives me this error,

```bsh
nuser@nserver:~$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-asn1crypto : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-certifi : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
 python3-chardet : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                   Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
 python3-debian : Depends: python3-six (> 1.4~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                  Recommends: python3-apt but it is not going to be installed
 python3-idna : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-linecache2 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pycurl : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 33.1.1-1+certbot~xenial+1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-testresources : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-traceback2 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-unittest2 : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python3-six (>= 1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-update-manager : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                          Depends: python3-apt (>= 0.8.5~) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: python3-distupgrade but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: lsb-release but it is not going to be installed
 python3-wheel : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                              Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python-apt-common (>= 0.9) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python3-dbus but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.10) but it is not going to be installed
 ufw : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Many Ubuntu tools are heavily reliant on python, and the specific version they come with (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3).   Removing and changing the default `python` (or `python3`) is not wise, and you should return it back to it's default. You can add a second python version if required.  Also note a fully upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 will report 16.04.7, so your system is badly behind (>2 years) on upgraded packages (*and thus hopefully not online*)

Comment: Did you uninstall the `python3` package?  If so, you might have seriously broken your system as apt itself relies on the `python3` package being present.  Never do a `make install` on python, always do `make localinstall` which leaves the system Python intact.

Comment: @BrianTurek I did remove the python3 package. Do you think a system reinstall would be required to fix this?

Comment: A re-install is often faster, and would bring your very *outdated/unmaintained* system up to date (I'd suggest 16.04.7 media), but you can install `python-minimal` package (using `dpkg`) and fix without re-install... You may need to do more than just this though

Comment: Thanks, @guiverc - I will give this a try.

Comment: See if `apt-get -f install` works and reinstalls python3.  If it does, you should be safe :)

Comment: @BrianTurek Just ran that command - Machine is doing more than it was before. I will let you know how I get on with this. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @BrianTurek and @ guiverc - I was able to fix this in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by deploying another instance of Ubuntu 16.04.

I copied the files that I deleted from `/usr/bin/py*` from the working instance, onto my broken machine.

This got me to a point where I could manually solve my individual errors by updating and removing broken links and packages.

Thank you @BrianTurek and @Guiverc for the help.