add-apt- or apt-add-repository missing in Docker ubuntu:precise (12.04.5) container
For compatibility, I need to use this old image but even after installing software-properties-common both commands are not found:
apt-add-repository or add-apt-repository
All I could find was to install software-properties-common but that does not help either.
FROM ubuntu:precise

# Set environment variables to avoid interactive prompts during package installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# Update package lists and install basic packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    curl \
    vim \
    wget \
    git \
    nano \
    software-properties-common \
    build-essential && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Start a shell by default when the container starts
CMD ["/bin/bash"]


Only supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM was in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/

By chance, I saw this answer after a minute of posting my question:
https://askubuntu.com/a/593437/909989
Basically, for older releases python-software-properties needs to be installed.
